# numpy svd: is there a way to find only the first singular vectors instead of doing full svd?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, svd

numpy.linalg.svd function gives the full svd of the input matrix. 
However I want only the first singular vectors.

I was wondering if there is any function in numpy for that or any other library in python?

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is [sklearn.utils.extmath.randomized_svd](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html)

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import randomized_svd
U, S, Vt = randomized_svd(X, n_components=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to randomized svd, you can run ARPACK on the squared problem, via [scipy.sparse.linalg.svds](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html).